# Turtle Boxes Repeating

Tags: python

I asked a question about this same code a yesterday, and now I have another question. The code is supposed to create 500 randomly colored boxes individually.  Instead, it draws each box in the same location. This is the code:

```
import turtle
from random import randint
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'blue', 'orange']
window = turtle.Screen()
window.title('500 Boxes')

for x in range(500):
    box = turtle.Turtle()
    box.color(colors[randint(0, 5)])
    for x in range(4):
        box.forward(30)
        box.left(90)

window.exitonclick()
```

I want to make each box a new variable, but I am not sure how.
I want each box to be 5 pixels away from each other box.
Thanks

Comment: OK, so we want randomly colored boxes. Where do you want to draw the other N number of boxes? randomly on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are expecting that each new Turtle:

```
box = turtle.Turtle()
```

to start from the same position than the last one, but you never coded that.

They all start from the same point, and do the same movements, and end up in the same place.

BTW, it's a good practice to avoid using the same variable names for nested iterations, even if it works as expected. You are using variable `x` in both `for`, I'd recommend using something else in the second `for`.

Answer (score 2):

You ARE creating a new variable each time in the loop. The problem is that each new turtle starts at the same location `(0, 0)`

To randomize the start location, you can make it go to a random x and y coordinate using the `'white'` color. Then do what you're already doing.

```
import turtle
from random import randint
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'blue', 'orange']
window = turtle.Screen()
window.title('500 Boxes')

for x in range(500):
    box = turtle.Turtle()

    box.color('white')
    box.setx(randint(-100, 100))
    box.sety(randint(-100, 100))

    box.color(colors[randint(0, 5)])
    for y in range(4):
        box.forward(30)
        box.left(90)

window.exitonclick()
```

Also, use different names for the loop variable in both the loops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the turtle!

Use `turtle.up()`, `turtle.down()`, and `turtle.goto(x, y)`

Here's my solution:

```
import turtle
from random import randint
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'blue', 'orange']
window = turtle.Screen()
window.title('500 Boxes')

turtle = turtle.Turtle()
for box in range(500):
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color(colors[randint(0, 5)])
    for x in range(4):
        turtle.forward(90)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.up()
    x = randint(-400, 400)
    y = randint(-400, 400)
    turtle.goto(x, y)


window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You're new, but best practice is to accept the answer that fixed your problem